# HLS video in VideoView suspend takes too much time in Nexus(Nexus 5 and Nexus 7)

Tags: android, video-streaming, android-videoview, http-live-streaming, nexus-5

I've the problem with VideoView. If i finish the VideoView activity app hanged. Because HLS video is buffering, it takes some time to suspend buffering video.